# maximized state `printpreviewdialog`

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using this code to print form, but I want the `printpreviewdialog`
to start in maximized state, how can I do this ??

I fined this code on another post here in the site :

```
  DirectCast(PrintPreviewDialog1, Form).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

but I'm not using the control `PrintPreviewDialog1`
so please help.

```
    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    PrintForm1.Print()
```

Comment: Word of advice:  I have a 43" monitor.  Starting _anything_ maximized is going to annoy me very quickly.

Comment: @DonBoitnott
yes I'm with you, but this is an one person application, and I need it to do something.